# Apache oozie database tool

Tags: java, apache, oozie

I've been following [these instructions](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.1/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_17_6.html) and got as far as "Creating the Oozie Database Schema"; I chose to run the tool and tried

> $ sudo -u oozie /usr/lib/oozie/bin/ooziedb.sh create -run

, which returned the following errors:

> Validate DB Connection
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
>   at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.setServiceInternal(Services.java:360)
>   at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.(Services.java:108)
>   at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.getJdbcConf(OozieDBCLI.java:161)
>   at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.createConnection(OozieDBCLI.java:461)
>   at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.validateConnection(OozieDBCLI.java:469)
>   at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.createDB(OozieDBCLI.java:179)
>   at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.run(OozieDBCLI.java:118)
>   at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.main(OozieDBCLI.java:64)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at org.apache.oozie.service.Service.(Service.java:60)
>   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
>   ...8 more

What might be the cause of this and how could I fix this?

Comment: which version of oozie are you using?

Comment: Sorry, this ceased to be a problem.

Comment: @Chiffa could you write how did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

edit the oozie-env.sh   at last  and  append **export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.7** the java_home is yourself javapath